# Node app treats escaped chars in path treated differently when installed globally

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I am very new to this Node stuff so there is probably a really simple answer to this but anyways...

I am building an app that prompts for a file path. This path is supplied by dropping a file into the Terminal window which gives a path with spaces escaped like this:

```
Users/[username]/Desktop/test\ file.txt
```

I then use [jsonfile](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonfile) to add this path to an array and write out a `JSON` file. In this file the path now has the *escape escaped* and looks like this:

```
Users/[username]/Desktop/test\\ file.txt
```

Now I want to grab that path from the JSON and reveal it in `Finder` and this is where I get lost. I am using [mac-open](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mac-open) to reveal the path by passing the `-R` option and this works fine while I am testing and running my code using `node bin/my-code.js` but as soon I install with `npm install -g .` it breaks. The install works and I can run the app (there are other functions that work fine) but now if I try to reveal the path I get the error:

```
{ [Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c open -a "Finder" -R "/Users/[username]/Desktop/test\\\ file.txt"
The file /Users/[username]/Desktop/test\\ file.txt does not exist.
]
  killed: false,
  code: 1,
  signal: null,
  cmd: '/bin/sh -c open -a "Finder" -R "/Users/[username]/Desktop/test\\\\\\ file.txt"' }
```

I have noticed the varying amounts of escapes in the different path references in the error so my questions are:

1. Why is this different when I test using `node bin/my-code.js`
   and when I install globally and run that way?
2. Is there a way that I can make the two behave the same as I don't really want to be installing every time I want to test my code?
3. Is there a more robust way of storing and/or escaping file paths?

Sorry this has got a bit rambling. Any advice welcome :)

Comment: You can avoid escaping, just put file path in quotes.

Comment: @loadaverage - I think my problem was that it was being escaped in too many places. ````Terminal```` was escaping the spaces then ````JSON```` was escaping the escape then ````mac-open```` was escaping the escaped escapes! In the end taking ````mac-open```` out of the equation fixed the issue and I learned a little bit along the way :)

Answer (score 0):

So I haven't exactly answered all the questions I posed but I have fixed the issue and learned what I consider a really valuable lesson in Node development.

Trying to find the problem I actually open the source [mac-open](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mac-open) and in doing so realised that I didn't actually need to be using the additional module at all. Searching the source led me to look into reading about [child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) and eventually sacking off the whole mac-open module for a simple:

```
var exec = require("child_process").exec;

exec("open " +assetsPath +" -R", function(err){
    if(err)
        console.log(err);
});
```

The esson here is not to use 3rd party modules just because they are there. In this situation I didn't need the all-situation covereage that it was trying to provide and the extra complexity actually caused the problem.